# Kill Switch schematic

Tags: switches, schematics, guitar-pedal, falstad

I want to make a kill-switch pedal with on/off LEDs for my guitar. I tested a simple [schematic](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000015625+10.20027730826997+50+5+50%0A162+32+144+256+144+1+2.1024259+1+0+0+0.01%0A162+128+176+240+176+1+2.1024259+1+0+0+0.01%0Ar+128+240+128+304+0+2200%0Aw+32+176+128+176+0%0Aw+32+144+32+176+0%0Aw+256+144+256+320+0%0Aw+240+176+240+288+0%0AS+128+304+240+304+0+0+false+0+2%0Aw+240+320+256+320+0%0AS+144+368+208+368+0+0+false+0+2%0Av+16+368+16+432+0+1+100+5+0+0+0.5%0Aw+208+352+256+352+0%0Aw+16+368+144+368+0%0Ag+16+432+16+464+0%0A211+256+352+336+352+0+1+8000+1%0Av+-32+144+32+144+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ag+-32+240+-32+288+0%0Aw+128+240+-32+240+0%0Aw+-32+240+-32+144+0%0Ax+120+124+168+127+4+24+OFF%0Ax+169+217+205+220+4+24+ON%0Aw+208+384+208+432+0%0Aw+16+432+208+432+0%0Ao+10+64+0+4099+5+0.00009765625+0+2+10+3%0Ao+14+64+0+4098+5+0.1+1+1%0A) but every time I ground the circuit like the schematic i put below i get an error:

> voltage source/wire loop with no resistance

Every kill-switch schematic I have seen, takes the Input sleeve to the Output sleeve and to the "off" lug of the switch without any resistor.

Is this something I should worry about?

Schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fj73hO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: When SW1 is on the bottom position, what do you think will happen to the bottom circuit? The "Kill" word seem to be appropriate.

Comment: Maybe it is a drawing problem? i am used to having tip sleeve as "input" and thought using an A/C source will be the same.

Comment: When the switch is on the other position, the bottom circuit is shorting the V2. This is what I see on the schematic.

Comment: Segmentation, that's right.  Your V2 symbol is considered a source, so the schematic implies that you're going to short-circuit that source.

Comment: Ok got it, how can i draw it then so it is not shorting the V2? As far as i know, I need to ground both the off position of the switch and the V2.

Comment: What's the purpose of the "drawing"? to simulate? Or to follow when constructing?

Comment: Follow when constructing and make me more familiar with drawing and reading schematics. After realizing i am shorting the source I get that the problem is that I don't really know how to draw it the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your Falstad simulator doesn't know that you're modelling a guitar pickup. You have used an ideal voltage source. When you short this out an infinite current will flow. You need some series resistance. See below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fC99Ym.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) Modified guitar mute and status indicator circuit. (b) Simple shorting mute switch. Note that pickup impedance needs to be added to work in simulation.*

- To mute the guitar you short the *amplifier input* to ground. Leaving it open-circuit will result in hum or buzz.
- You could just use one pole of SW1 to short the pickup to ground as shown in Figure 1b. The pickup has a high internal resistance and won't suffer. This arrangement also has the advantage that you never leave the amplifier input floating during changeover. In fact many guitar pickup selector switches are "make before break" types for this reason. Note to avoid complaints from your simulator you would need to add the pickup series resistance after the sine generator. 100k might be a good value.

I've rearranged the LEDs just to avoid cross-over of wiring. Your original scheme was OK.

Comment: I don't really get the right schematic. Isn't it doing the same thing I did with shorting the source?

Comment: It is and it will work in the real world but not in the simulator. I explained it in the first paragraph. Read it again and ask if clarification is required.